# Android device is not connecting

Tags: android

I have tried following option but not working.

1. Reinstalling Google USB drive.
2. In Control Panel troubleshooting hardware after apply fix it shows following[image]
3. In device Manger, in Other device ADB is not there and under android device  Android ADB interface is with some warning as shown in below [image]
4. When I clicked on Android ADB Interface it gives an error This device cannot start. (Code 10) 
   [image]

Comment: Have you enabled `USB Debugging`?

Comment: Yes I have enabled my USB Debugging

Comment: I don't know what the issue is but I found many solutions/results on searching some of those errors on Google. A solution from [MakeUseOf](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/android-wont-connect-windows-adb-fix-it-three-steps/)

Comment: The Google USB drivers are only for Google devices (without modifying it). Get the proper (ADB) drivers from Motorola or use the universal ADB drivers.

Answer (score 0):

[Google - Install OEM USB Drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb)

1. Open above link and scroll down till end
2. Download the OEM respective adb drivers
3. Go to device manager and update the drivers from the machine
4. Apart from adb drivers, you might need Qualcomm USB drivers to resolve your issue